# Check if element is in viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code which works fine to understand if an element is inside the viewport. I would like to write to the console once when it is in the viewport and once when it is not (and not continuously as it does now).

```
$.fn.isInViewport = function() {
    var elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
    var elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();

    var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();

    return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
};

$(window).on('resize scroll', function() {
    if ($('#Something').isInViewport()) {
        console.log('in viewport');
    } else {
        console.log('not in viewport');
    }
});
```

edit:
thanks, i tried your code and it works fine but i can't fit it to my context with multiple elements

```
var sur = document.getElementsByClassName("survey");


    let wasInViewPort;
    $(window).on('resize scroll', function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < sur.length; i++) {
        const isInViewPort = $(sur[i]).isInViewport();
        if (isInViewPort !== wasInViewPort) {
          var a = isInViewPort ? ' in viewport' : ' not in viewport';
            console.log(sur[i].id+a);
        }
        wasInViewPort = isInViewPort;
      }
    
    
    });
```

Comment: You need to track the scroll-wheel and mouse click-drag movement.

Comment: You can try to check if that elements vertical offset is greater then the scroll top but less then the difference between the scroll top and the inner height of the window

Comment: Cache the value somewhere: if the Boolean is flipped then log to console.

Comment: My code already works perfectly, I just want it to activate when an element is visible and subsequently activate when it is no longer visible

Comment: you should look into caching `$('#Something')` outside the scroll handler

Answer (score 2):

Just use a variable to keep track of the last result, and only call `console.log` when that changes:

```js
let wasInViewPort;
$(window).on('resize scroll', function() {
    const isInViewPort = $('#Something').isInViewport();
    if (isInViewPort !== wasInViewPort) {
        console.log(`${isInViewPort ? '' : 'not '}in viewport`);
    }
    wasInViewPort = isInViewPort;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried your code and it works fine but i can't fit it to my context with multiple elements

Comment: Do you mean you have elements other than `#Something` and you want to track their status in/out of the viewport independently? That's certainly possible but is a very different question from the one you asked. By all means ask that as a new question if you want to.